# Error when switching Django project to gunicorn server in virtualenv

Tags: django, django-models, virtualenv, gunicorn

I have a project that creates objects that I would like to key with uuids. When I run this project with the simple Django test server in manage.py everything works great. However I am trying to deploy to heroku, so I have set up a virtualenv with a gunicorn server which breaks my code. I have traced the error to the fact that for some reason my UploadedFile objects always have a blank access link when run with this server.

Here is the code from my models.py:

```
 from django.db import models
 import uuid
 import datetime

 # UUID field will be used to key file upload objects
 class UUIDField(models.CharField) :
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     kwargs['max_length'] = kwargs.get('max_length', 64 )
     kwargs['blank'] = True
     models.CharField.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

 class UploadedFile(models.Model):
   #accessLink = UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
   accessLink = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
   uploadTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)  
   filename = models.CharField(max_length=200)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(UploadedFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     if self.accessLink is '':
       self.accessLink = str(uuid.uuid4())

   def __unicode__(self):
     return filename
```

Here is the code for my index contained in views.py:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse  # Just for lulz                                            
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.core.context_processors import csrf
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.template import Template, Context
 from smartfile import BasicClient
 from filemapper.models import UploadedFile

 def index(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
     c = {}
     c.update(csrf(request))
     authKey = 'ggcCEFzGBcJYAQSHNf7AnF8r7c03cB'
     authPassword = 'CJlxZHCocieiPOKuhI6GdGOwwTMr2i'
     api = BasicClient(authKey, authPassword)
     for f in request.FILES.values():
       # Create our record of the file
       u = UploadedFile(filename=f.name) 
       u.save()
       # Create a directory on smartfile
       api.post('/path/oper/mkdir/', path=u.accessLink)
       # Upload the file to s
       api.post('/path/data/' + u.accessLink, file=f.file, name=u.filename)
       # This page should display how to access the uploade
       return generate(request, u.accessLink)
     else:
       return HttpResponse('File not found')
   else:
     return render(request, 'filemapper/index.html')
```

The code fails when I try to POST a file to the index, since u.accessLink is not a correctly formed UUID, it is a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here that I as a Django developer would do the other way:

- there is no need to code UUIDField, just use a char field with `max_length` and `blank=True`
- don't override `UploadedFile.__init__` - set accessLink in `UploadedFile.save()` method

Also, when overloading new style class methods, you should use `super`, not call the `__init__` method explicitly.